# Event Error - civi_flexmailer_required_tokens

Tags: civievent, civimail

Everytime I try to make an event, or access any page with event information, I get the following error:

`You have requested a non-existent service "civi_flexmailer_required_tokens".`

Using latest Civi 5, Wordpress 4.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem after upgrading from Drupal 8 to 9 and upgrading Civi to 5.51.1. Thanks to @seamuslee on [Mattermost](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/wkf38q1a7jn4ifrwiaxeebfetw) for solving this issue for me. These are the steps I followed on a Drupal installation to fix it:

1. Disable Mosaico in Extensions
2. Disable Flexmailer in Extensions
3. Delete the Flexmailer extension directory (`/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.flexmailer`)
4. Clear Civi caches and rebuild paths/menus at `/civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1`
5. Enable Flexmailer in Extensions
6. Enable Mosaico in Extensions

This issue is also answered at [CiviCRM core now includes Flexmailer: how to remove old flexmailer extension?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39134/civicrm-core-now-includes-flexmailer-how-to-remove-old-flexmailer-extension)

Comment: that rocks! thanks Ben and Seamus

Answer (score 6):

we have similar issue but after clearing civicrm cache using menu/rebuild it started working.

Comment: For drupal civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1

Answer (score 2):

We were seeing the same problem after upgrade to CiviCRM 5.0.2.  This is a detail follow-up on Sunil's answer above (*sorry, didn't have enough reputation points to comment on his directly and thought this would be useful.*)...

The URL to clear the CiviCRM Cache is:

http://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1

Answer (score 0):

Still figuring this out - but disabling Event Calendar (com.osseed.eventcalendar) fixed the issue.

Update: Cleaned up Cache - error persisted, Cleaned up cache and rebuilt CiviCRM menu - re-enabled com.oosseed.eventcalendar - all good to go.