# Error when merging accounts

Tags: duplicate-contacts

When attempting to merge accounts, I receive this message:

CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "You have requested a non-existent service "prevnext.driver.". Did you mean one of these: "prevnext.driver.redis", "prevnext.driver.sql"?"

How might I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Might be similar to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24479/event-error-civi-flexmailer-required-tokens. Try the answers there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue once, I changed the value for "PrevNext Cache" from "Default(Auto-detect)" to "SQL" under Administer > System Settings > Misc. This fixed the issue