# Recipient loading failed in mailing after upgrade to 5.65.1

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, groups, mailing

I am running Civicrm on Wordpress 6.3.1 and today I upgraded Civicrm from 5.58.1 to 5.65.1 successfully with no errors. Log output - [info] Running task: Finish core DB updates 5.65.1

I did notice some other warnings -

[warning] ManagedEntity update policy "unmodified" specified for entity type SearchDisplay which is not an APIv4 ManagedEntity. Falling back to policy "always"

[warning] \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event is deprecated. Consider using \Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent. For more information see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/usage/symfony/#events Caller: Civi\FlexMailer\Validator::run]

[warning] Deprecated function CRM_Utils_Token::getTokenDetails, use If you hit this in mailing code you should use flexmailer - otherwise use the token processor.
CRM_Core_Error::deprecatedFunctionWarning
CRM_Utils_Token::getTokenDetails
CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob::deliverGroup
CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob::deliver
Array
(
[civi.tag] => deprecated
)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I am not sure if my issues below is related to the above warnings.

#1. I was testing mailings after the upgrade I have noticed that the recipient field was empty (but showing the number of recipients {3 in this case} for a previous *draft* email). The error that I am getting is "Loading failed" when trying to select another group of recipients.

#2. I tried a new mailing and I get the same error "Loading failed" and am unable to select any group recipients.

In case #1 above the mail does get sent to the recipients.

I have attached a screen shot.

I am running Flexmailer.

Any help would be appreciated

Many Thanks

[image: Error I am getting]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have a non-core version of Flexmailer in the mix (like Flexmailer 1.1.1 instead of Flexmailer 5.65). See [this past question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39134/civicrm-core-now-includes-flexmailer-how-to-remove-old-flexmailer-extension) for instructions to remove.

Per the previous question, the steps are disable Mosaico, then Flexmailer. Delete the Flexmailer directory. Clear the caches. Enable the new Flexmailer, then Mosaico. Perform database upgrades if a message tells you to.

Comment: Thanks Lars SG....I did check and I noticed that I had Flexmailer 1.1.2 instead of Flexmailer 5.65....I have checked the past question for instructions....I have another problem as I am having problem installing command line interface to run cv commands....is there another way to update to Flexmailer 5.65 through UI?

Comment: I've added instructions to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks @Lars My steps of what I  did (Managed to get CLI working)
From Extensions. Directory
1. copied flexmailer to different directory just in case I need it.
2. cv dis mosaico flexmailer
3. rm -rf org.civicrm.flexmailer     when I did this,  it did not remove the directory/contents so I used rm -rf flexmailer  4. cv flush
5. cv en flexmailer mosaico >>>>>error Extension cache does not contain requested item(s) Refreshing extension cache >>>Error: Unrecognized extension "flexmailer"
I noticed in Adminster>System Settings>Extensions that FlexMailer was disabled and in red

Comment: I am now a little lost on what to do next as it is not picking up new Flexmailer but shows  Flexmailer 1.1.2.

Comment: ...Would you suggest that I revert back to v5.58.1 as I have the files and database and then remove Fleximailer v1.1.2. Once this is done to upgrade the system to 5.65.1?

Comment: Sounds like you deleted the current Flexmailer and kept the old one, because you were in the CiviCRM/ext directory (which is for extensions that come with CiviCRM) instead of the extensions directory for added extensions (normally in /wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext). So, put the one you deleted back, go to the added extensions directory and follow the same procedure there.

Comment: ..thks..here is what I have done. I have brought the flexmailer directory/files back into ~/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext
Just fyi, I do not have flexmailer Directory or flexmailer files in ~/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext 
I only have ca.civicrm.logviewer, mosaicotweaks, uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico and webtracking-1.3(not used) in this drectory Adminster>System Settings>Extensions shows Flexmailer 5.65.1.
“Loading failed” still comes up when accessing draft mailings.

Comment: Error log has many warning entries - [warning] ManagedEntity update policy "unmodified" specified for entity type SearchDisplay which is not an APIv4 ManagedEntity. Falling back to policy "always"
Any other suggestions to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are both Mosaico and Flexmailer enabled? Cleared the cache?

Comment: yes, I enabled both and can see them in Adminster>System Settings>Extensions shows Flexmailer 5.65.1 (status required with green tick and no uninstall option) and Mosaico 3.2.1691060437 with green tick. yes I performed cv flush.

Comment: That's a weird warning. Not sure what to make of it. Are they all about Managed Entities or other things too? Do you get a specific error when you try to open a new mailing for instance?

Comment: No specific error in the Civicrm logs......it is primary domain with a CiviCRM Db and a subdomain with a separate CiviCrm Db on the same physical server......the subdomain works fine.......what next steps would you like me try out as I have asked our user community to not use Civi for mail outs till I can rectify. Would re-installing core s'ware help and what would be the steps.?By the way the managed entity warnings have surfaced after the upgrade only.

Comment: The following has appeared in the last hour.....[error] 
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "You do not have permission to access this page."
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#22537
    -errorData: array:1 [
      "error_code" => 0
    ]
    #cause: null
    -_trace: null
    #message: "You do not have permission to access this page."
    #code: 0
    #file: "/example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php"
    #line: 605
and this continues....

Comment: trace: {      /example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:605 {
        CRM_Utils_System_WordPress->permissionDenied()
        ›   $civicrm_wp_title = ts('You do not have permission to access this page.');
        ›   throw new CRM_Core_Exception(ts('You do not have permission to access this page.'));
        › }      }      /example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php:62 { …}
      /example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Page/View.php:140 { …}
.......

Comment: /example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:319 { …}
      /example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /example.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1199 { …}
      /example.org/httpdocs/wp-

Comment: content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php:380 { …} /example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310 { …} /example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:334 { …} /example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php:565 { …} /example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp.php:796 { …} /example.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php:1335 { …} /example.org/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php:16 { …} /example.org/httpdocs/index.php:17 { …}........ I'm not sure what this is about???..Probably unrelated to what info we exchanging earlier

Comment: Yes, those might be unrelated to the mailings issue. Are you sure the mailings issue you are having now came after the Flexmailer changes? Or possibly just after the upgrade?

Comment: Check if all core extensions (CiviContribute, CiviMail, etc) are enabled in Extensions and enabled as Components.

Comment: The mailing issue was immediately (100%) after the upgrade. I have now enabled all core extensions that were in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext through the UI which are as follows...
CiviCase, CiviCampaign, CiviPledge, admin UI, Search UI, CiciGrant, CiviImports, iATSpayments, Elavon payment processor, OAuth Client, payflowpro
Cleared cache with CV flush
The mailing issue still exists....
Error log has many warning entries - [warning] ManagedEntity update policy "unmodified" specified for entity type SearchDisplay which is not an APIv4 ManagedEntity. Falling back to policy "always"

Comment: ...what would be my next steps?

Comment: This Warning has appeared in the last 1 hr. 
 [warning] Civi\Api4\Generic\BasicBatchAction constructor received $doer as a non-callable; the 3rd param as the $select param has been removed Caller: Civi\Api4\Action\OAuthSysToken\Refresh::__construct
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)
is this because OAuth Client was installed?

Comment: I now can't get to administer >System Settings>Scheduled Jobs screen.
The error is - Invalid field 'saved_search.name'
Does this give us some clues for the mailing perhaps?

Comment: Oh, I just meant the core extensions that have core components (CiviMail, CiviEvent, etc). Did you check that CiviMail is enabled as an extension and also enabled as a component (Administer -> System Settings -> Extensions and -> Components)?

Comment: Otherwise, it sounds like possibly an issue to do with SearchKit. You can check that, but you might want to consider going to your backup at this point, switching Flexmailer before upgrading, and trying the upgrade again. It's possible something went wrong in the upgrade process.

Comment: Can I turn off Search kit first? Should I leave out core CiviCrm components which I turned on today before the upgrade or turn it on after the upgrade?

Comment: I took your advise and did some investigative work. Your suggestion of Search_kit was correct. 
I renamed my Search_Kit and copied search_kit to the extensions directory from my subdomain server. I Uninstall Extensions - SearchUI, OAuth Client only.

Comment: The only warnings that I am getting are 1.  [warning] Deprecated function CRM_Core_BAO_Job::retrieve, use API. 2 [warning] Deprecated function Civi\Angular\AngularLoader::setModules, use addModules. 3. [warning] Deprecated function Civi\Angular\AngularLoader::load, use angularjs.loader service. The other errors (e.g. ManagedEntity) are not present. 
Hence I think that the mailing issue may have been resolved for now except for the warnings above. I will keep you posted after I do some testing.  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Any suggestions on these 3 warnings? 
btw, I didnt roll back to the pre upgrade files.

Comment: I have also disabled  CiviCase to check if stops the “angular” warnings. 
I have also disabled CiviGrant and Civicampaign as we do not use these functions.

Btw, what is the yellow icon (that looks like a flask) in the extensions UI?

Comment: Yeah, search kit is required now, I'm not sure you ended up without it. The little flask means it is pre-release, not a mature extension (hover over it, there is help text). Your other warnings may or may not be meaningful, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks @Lars....I had an earlier beta version of Serchkit when I compared with my other server. I do have a number of extensions that are pre-release. AuthX, Civicrm Admin UI, CivicImport. {Afform Core Runtime, HTML, Form builder}...Do I need Afform set of extensions? as I believe it is contributing to  [warning] Deprecated function Civi\Angular\AngularLoader::load, use angularjs.loader service.

Comment: You should have up to date versions of all the extensions that come with core, none of them should be different versions than the core version. The civicrm/ext directory is part of the upgrade process. Afform core is required.

Comment: Many Thanks @Lars SG...I've been checking our set up and  the following core modules are *Not* 5.65.1...
CiviGrant 5.57.0 (we do not use this)
CiviGrant 5.57.0 (we do not use this)
IATs Payments 1.7.5 (we do not use this)
Contribution cancel actions 1.0
 Elavon Payment Processor 5.57.0
OAuth Client 1.0 
Afform x 3 - 0.5 with "Flask"
Admin UI although has the right version but has a flask.
Payflowpro 1.0

How do I get them all to 5.65.1?

Comment: I'm not sure what's up, but all the 5.57 ones should be upgraded when you upgrade. If they aren't being upgraded, then you should try to figure out why. I don't know. Maybe a permissions issue, like the upgrader can't delete the existing versions?
IATS is not in core, nor contribution cancel actions.
But both oauth client and afform should be 5.65. Sounds like you might have the same problem as flexmailer for those.

Comment: Many thanks for your help as I would not have progressed this far ;-)....I will investigate and report any findings.

Comment: Easiest probably just to delete them and replace with ones from the new version, but might be worth figuring out what went wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error since upgrading to 5.64.4 on one site (Joomla not WP). FlexMailer info.xml states it's 5.64.4 so not sure it's the same cause, but definitely the same 'loading failed' error in CiviMail.

The console gives me a 500 error on this URL when trying the lookup: `https://www.---.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/api4/EntitySet/autocomplete&params={"input":"","page":1,"formName":"crmMailing.479","fieldName":"Mailing.recipients_include"}&_=16951239190`.

This makes it sound similar to this error: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3587 - but I have other API4 calls working ok, it seems (e.g. contact lookup).

Comment: I did take a look and cannot reproduce.   The only suggestions I have are what I am sure you've already done.  Be sure o other flexmailer extensions are installed and flush all cv caches.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem for the last few months. Flexmailer is up to date. I tried disabling it, but it's showing as "Required", and cv won't let me disable it either. Is this normal?

At the "Loading failed" error, the console shows a 500 error on GET https://domain.co.uk/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Fapi4%2FEntitySet%2Fautocomplete&params=%7B%22input%22%3A%22%22%2C%22page%22%3A1%2C%22formName%22%3A%22crmMailing.628%22%2C%22fieldName%22%3A%22Mailing.recipients_include%22%7D&_=1695635330283

Any suggestions as to what could be causing this? Thanks.