# Recipient loading failed in mailing since (at least) 5.64, Joomla

Tags: civimail, joomla

I have the same error described [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45535/recipient-loading-failed-in-mailing-after-upgrade-to-5-65-1) for WordPress and [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45605/loading-failed-when-selecting-recipient-group-in-civimail-mailing) for Drupal - but on Joomla.

The console error is a 500 on the URL –

```
"https://example.com/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/api4/EntitySet/autocomplete&params={"input":"a","page":1,"formName":"crmMailing.493","fieldName":"Mailing.recipients_include"}&_=1700243283373
[HTTP/2 500  460ms]
```

Any help gratefully received - I think this happened after a recent upgrade.

[image: Screengrab of loading failed in mail screen]