I get this warning message. And seem to have lost data...added files and documents
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The "civi_flexmailer_required_tokens" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead. in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->make() (line 275 of /home/rws/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Container.php).

what version of what are you using?

it maybe a case that FlexMailer has shifted from being in Core to being an Extension, or similar change. check https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39134/civicrm-core-now-includes-flexmailer-how-to-remove-old-flexmailer-extension

As Pete says, it would be helpful if you could provide more information. What version of CiviCRM are you using? What CMS? What were you doing when you got this message? Etc.
